How select query from record count more than 2 with custom column (Option) in MS Access
I'm trying to select query from row count more than 2 based on ID and DATE and OPTION in MS Access.
so with "NO" in the option column then the record more than 2 is not included in my sql query code
Is there something wrong with my SQL code ?
so my post is different from the link below
link
Please Guide me
Table Absen



ID
DATE
TIME
INOUT
OPTION




5008
28-Apr-24
08:00
IN



5008
28-Apr-24
17:00
OUT



5009
29-Apr-24
08:00
IN



5009
29-Apr-24
17:00
OUT



5009
29-Apr-24
17:00
OUT
NO


5010
28-Apr-24
08:00
IN



5011
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN



5011
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN



5011
30-Apr-24
17:00
OUT




Table MASTERID



ID
NAMEID
POSITIONID




5008
A
STAFF


5009
B
STAFF


5010
C
STAFF


5011
D
STAFF



I used this SQL code result like this:
SELECT a.ID, MASTERID.NAMEID, a.DATE, a.TIME, a.INOUT
FROM ABSEN AS a INNER JOIN MASTERID ON a.ID = MASTERID.ID
WHERE a.option is null and exists(select a.ID from ABSEN a2 where a.ID=a2.ID and a.DATE=a2.DATE group by a.ID and a.DATE and a.option having count(*) > 2)
ORDER BY a.ID, a.DATE, a.INOUT;

Result From code



ID
NAMEID
DATE
TIME
INOUT




5009
B
29-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5009
B
29-Apr-24
17:00
OUT


5011
D
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5011
D
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5011
D
30-Apr-24
17:00
OUT



Desired result



ID
NAMEID
DATE
TIME
INOUT




5011
D
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5011
D
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5011
D
30-Apr-24
17:00
OUT



Table Absen for testing answer from @june7



ID
DATE
TIME
INOUT
OPTION




5008
28-Apr-24
08:00
IN



5008
28-Apr-24
17:00
OUT



5009
29-Apr-24
08:00
IN



5009
29-Apr-24
17:00
OUT



5009
29-Apr-24
17:00
OUT
NO


5010
28-Apr-24
08:00
IN



5011
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN



5011
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN



5011
30-Apr-24
17:00
OUT



5011
28-Aug-24
08:00
IN



5011
28-Aug-24
17:00
OUT



5011
29-Aug-24
08:00
IN



5011
29-Aug-24
17:00
OUT




Result from answer from @june7



ID
NAMEID
DATE
TIME
INOUT




5011
D
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5011
D
30-Apr-24
08:00
IN


5011
D
30-Apr-24
17:00
OUT


5011
D
28-Aug-24
08:00
IN


5011
D
28-Aug-24
17:00
OUT


5011
D
29-Aug-24
08:00
IN


5011
D
29-Aug-24
17:00
OUT



Table Absen for testing answer update from @june7 28-08-2024



ID
DATE
TIME
INOUT
OPTION




5045
12-Jul-24
08:11:36
IN



5045
12-Jul-24
08:11:38
IN



5045
12-Jul-24
17:01:01
IN



5045
12-Jul-24
0
OUT



5045
21-Jun-24
08:16:10
IN



5045
21-Jun-24
17:04:45
OUT



5045
22-Jun-24
08:18:14
IN



5045
21-May-24
08:19:25
IN



5045
21-May-24
17:04:40
OUT
NO



Table MASTERID



ID
NAMEID
POSITIONID




5045
M
STAFF



with Code Answer update
SELECT a.ID, m.NAMEID, a.DATE, a.TIME, a.INOUT
FROM ABSEN AS a INNER JOIN MASTERID AS m ON a.ID = m.ID
WHERE a.ID NOT IN(select ID from ABSEN WHERE Option="NO")
AND m.POSITIONID ='STAFF' and a.ID & [Date] IN(SELECT ID & [Date] FROM ABSEN GROUP BY ID & [Date] HAVING Count(*)>2)
ORDER BY a.ID, a.DATE, a.INOUT;

Result Answer update (no record)



ID
NAMEID
DATE
TIME
INOUT



with old code posting
SELECT a.ID, MASTERID.NAMEID, a.Date, a.Time, a.INOUT
FROM ABSEN AS a INNER JOIN MASTERID ON a.ID = MASTERID.ID
WHERE (((MASTERID.POSITIONID)='STAFF') AND ((a.OPTION) Is Null) AND ((Exists (select a.ID from ABSEN a2 where a.ID=a2.ID and a.DATE=a2.DATE group by a.ID having count(*) > 2))<>False))
ORDER BY a.ID, a.Date, a.INOUT;


Result old code posting



ID
NAMEID
DATE
TIME
INOUT




5045
M
12-Jul-24
17:01:01
IN


5045
M
12-Jul-24
08:11:38
IN


5045
M
12-Jul-24
08:11:36
IN


5045
M
12-Jul-24
0
OUT




To clarify: you want (5009, 29-Apr-2024) (three rows) to be excluded fro your query because one or more of them has OPTION='NO'? If yes, just change your GROUP by in EXISTS subquery to 'group by a.ID, a.DATE' (remove OPTION and use commas to separate columns to group by).

@tinazmu , you want (5009, 29-Apr-2024) (three rows) to be excluded from your query because one or more of them has OPTION='NO'?  If there is a 'NO' option then it is not counted as a record that is more than 2 as an example 5009, 29-Apr-2024 . Okay I will try

@tinazmu , I've tried it but for (5009, 29-Apr-2024) appear 2 records  but what I want (5009, 29-Apr-2024)  does not appear anymore because it is not more than 2 records with the help column OPTION

@tinazmu , Is there any other solution?, please guide me from you

Why did you use GROUP BY ID & [Date] ; you should use comma , to separate columns in the GROUP BY. Your requirement around OPTION is unclear to me.  it is not more than 2 records with the help column OPTION; explain what this means a bit further (how do you use the OPTION column; are the blank ones actually NULL or blank; how do you treat N, blank, null, or any other value?

@tinazmu , Why did you use GROUP BY ID & [Date] ; you should use comma , to separate columns in the GROUP BY.  This is with Code Answer update from june7 and  code my sql with old code posting

@tinazmu , Your requirement around OPTION is unclear to me.  it is not more than 2 records with the help column OPTIONThe purpose of the option column with the value 'NO' is to declare that the record is not selected again in the record more than 2 so for example 5009with date29-Apr-24` this includes record more 2 so if one of my records uses the option column with 'NO' then the status of record more 2 it means lost

still not clear: you don't have ID:5008 in your desired output, for example, why?

@tinazmu , Because 5008 only two record not record more 2 and has  IN and OUT so it's 5008 not a double category

@tinazmu , so the point is that the record is more than 2 with ID & DATE but if it includes the 'NO' option then the record is reduced

You want to list rows if ID&DATE appear more than twice (not counting rows with OPTION='N'):
SELECT a.ID, MASTERID.NAMEID, a.DATE, a.TIME, a.INOUT
FROM ABSEN AS a 

     INNER JOIN MASTERID 
     ON a.ID = MASTERID.ID
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM ABSEN AS a2
       WHERE a.ID = a2.ID 
         and a.DATE = a2.DATE
         and IIF(a2.OPTION IS NULL, '', a2.OPTION) <> 'NO'
       ) > 2
ORDER BY a.ID, a.DATE, a.INOUT;


Your answer is perfect and sorry I was late replying

I have a new post and I use your answer in this post so I hope you can help. link

Use 2 nested queries and IN() function:
SELECT a.ID, m.NAMEID, a.DATE, a.TIME, a.INOUT
FROM ABSEN AS a INNER JOIN MASTERID AS m ON a.ID = m.ID
WHERE a.ID NOT IN(select ID from ABSEN WHERE Option="NO")
AND a.ID IN(SELECT ID FROM ABSEN GROUP BY ID HAVING Count(*)>2)
ORDER BY a.ID, a.DATE, a.INOUT;

Based on revised sample data:
SELECT a.ID, m.NAMEID, a.DATE, a.TIME, a.INOUT
FROM ABSEN AS a INNER JOIN MASTERID AS m ON a.ID = m.ID
WHERE a.ID NOT IN(select ID from ABSEN WHERE Option="NO")
AND a.ID & [Date] IN(SELECT ID & [Date] FROM ABSEN GROUP BY ID & [Date] HAVING Count(*)>2)
ORDER BY a.ID, a.DATE, a.INOUT;


Thanks for your answer but I'm trying to add a record for ID 5011 With 28-Aug-24 with each in out But the record appeared after I updated your answer

I'm updating in the post Table Absen for testing answer from @june7 and Result from answer from @june7

See revised answer.

Thanks for your answer . I'm analyzing it in the actual MS access So give me time to analyze and mark your answers, but not all of them appear double. Example m.NAMEID='A' If I use the where condition where I put in your SQL answer code Is it before this code a.ID NOT IN(select ID from ABSEN WHERE Option="NO") . Is it like thisWHERE m.NAMEID='A'  and a.ID NOT IN(select ID from ABSEN WHERE Option="NO")

Sorry, I don't understand your comment. The query I posted produces the desired output shown in your question.

Sorry For late respond, for misunderstandings, You can see from the MS Access file that I shared link. I make two query recordcountmorethan2OLD this is in my posting and recordcountmorethan2frjune7 This is your updated answer. So the result of your answer query there is a record that is not included, I don't know why

SO policy is all info to analyze issue should be within question, not download files. Many will not download from external site. Could post to a discussion forum that allows attaching files to post.

Okay, I've posted a testing table so you can try with updated answers so you know where the problem is Table Absen for testing answer update from @june7 28-08-2024
